# Umbraco: custom member types using config file

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am creating member type using config file as below:

```
  <membertype alias="custommember" name="Custom Member">
    <tab alias="general" name="General Details">

      <property alias="contactphone" name="Contact Phone Number" type="Umbraco.Textbox" datatype="nvarchar" description="Either Mobile or Landline. If a mobile is enters SMS notifications are provided"/>

      <property alias="emailaddress" name="Email Address" type="Umbraco.Textbox" datatype="nvarchar" description="The primary contact email address of the member" />

    </tab>
```

i am trying to add validation property in phone and email address, any idea which property i need to call?
like for phone only number are allowed and for email : 11xx@xx.com  only this format allowed.

Thanks

Comment: Which Umbraco version are you on?

Comment: @jannik.... Umbraco v7

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom member types (or edit the default) directly inside Umbraco 7, you don't have to do it through a config file. Inside Umbraco there's a validation field and everything.

Under Members, right click Member Types, choose Create, and voila :-)

If nothing else, you might be able to spot what changes (if any, but I don't think config files are used anymore) are made to config files when you create a custom membertype inside Umbraco, and use those changes elsewhere.